# How to calculate distance between points (with UTM coordinates) in Rstudio?

Tags: distance, rstudio

I have points on a QGIS map, and want to determine the distance between each of the points in Rstudio. Each Unique ID is a tree. The coordinates are UTM coordinates (x = East, y = North)

My dataset looks like this:

| Unique_ID | EW_X | EW_Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 45 | 573500 | 775011 |
| 49 | 572224 | 774700 |
| 70 | 573573 | 775200 |
| 71 | 573573 | 775200 |

What formula would I use so I can get an output that describes the distance between each tree, looking like this (where x is the distance between each tree):

| Unique_ID | 45 | 49 | 70 | 71 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 45 |  | x | x | x |
| 49 | x |  | x | x |
| 70 | x | x |  | x |
| 71 | x | x | x |  |

Or perhaps if it is more simple, repeated rows (e.g. 45 against 49, 45 against 70, 45 against 71; and etc. with each repetition being a new row).

Comment: Are you looking for help with the mathematical formula to calculate the distance between UTM coordinates or with how to code this in R?

Comment: How to code this in R - if I've published this question on the wrong Stackexchange website my apologies!